# how to continue performing actions on next element with foreachordered on exception?

Tags: java, foreach, parallelstream

Just trying out a simple example to understand exception handling when it comes to streaming with foreachordered. Please write down suggestions on how we can continue performing actions on next element of list(20) when the current element threw exception (1).

```
  try {
      List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10, 1, 20, 15, 2); 
      list.stream().forEachOrdered(num->{
          if(num>2) {
              System.out.println(num);
          }else {
              int result=num/0;
              System.out.println(result);
          }
      });
      
      
  }catch(Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Exception: "+e);
      
  }
```

Comment: you need to try/catch the exception within the `forEachOrdered`, not outside of it.

Comment: @luk2302 write it as an answer please, so the question can be marked as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to continue the cycle you need to catch the exception within it

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(10, 1, 20, 15, 2); 
list.stream().forEachOrdered(num -> {
    if(num > 2) {
        System.out.println(num);
    } else {
        try {
            int result = num/0;
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

This way when the exception is caught and handled it doesn't interfere with the next cycle. You could of course put the whole condition from `if` into the try-catch block, but there is no reason to do so.